# Where to find logs for failed VSTest in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, vstest

Have an Azure Devops pipeline for app service deployment running on hosted agent in Windows 2019 VM inside of a VNET.  Last step of of deployment tasks is to run integration tests but its failing with unhelpful stack trace (microsoft callstack).

Here is the YAML for that step:

```yaml
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run Integration Tests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_FooService pipeline/drop/output/FooServiceTests.Integration.dll'
```

Here is last bit of devops logs

```yaml
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0902607Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0903591Z    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0904073Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0904563Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0905027Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClient[T]()
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0905523Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.RestApiHelpers.TcmTestExecutionServiceRestApiHelper..ctor(String project)
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0906060Z    at MS.VS.TestService.VstestConsoleAdapter.VstestConsoleRunContext.InitializeRestApiHelper()
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0906556Z    at MS.VS.TestService.VstestConsoleAdapter.VstestConsoleRunContext.CreateRunContext()
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0907032Z    at MS.VS.TestService.VstestConsoleAdapter.VstestConsoleRunContext.get_Instance()
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0907540Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.LocalTestRunHost.Execute(Boolean debugLogs)
2020-09-25T01:00:48.0908043Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
2020-09-25T01:00:48.1629868Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2020-09-25T01:00:48.1631712Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Users\TestAdmin\agent\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ed087383-ee5e-42c7-8a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530
2020-09-25T01:00:48.1634275Z ##[error]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
```

Where can I find the logs to show more detail as to why the test is failing?

Comment: Is there a "Tests" tab you can click on?  Usually that might have the trace for the test.  All you'd be getting in the logs is for the agent execution.  You could also probably go to the Test Runs area and find it.

Comment: I checked the "Tests" tab and here is what it says :  "No test runs are available for this build. Run tests and get rich reports by using an appropriate built-in task such as the Visual Studio Test task. Alternately, run tests using a runner of your choice such as JUnit, xUnit, mocha, jest, pytest, rspec, etc. and use the Publish Test Results task to get rich reports."

Comment: Can you share some details about your whole pipeline definitions? And add some code snippet to help us reproduce the issue?

Comment: Using a windows self hosted agent to build / deploy / run tests. Had to fix a few things but finally have better logs...   Someone had configured OS level proxy (which wasnt running).  Had to turn this off.  Also, had to add xunit.runner.json config file to test project in VStudio.  Also had to use XUntil ITestOutputHelper to log the service URL to the xunit output.

Comment: What's the result if you run the tests locally with command-line? And since you're running Xunit tests, have you tried [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#run-your-tests)? Can it make any difference?

Comment: Release serviceUrl environment variable was incorrect.  XUntil ITestOutputHelper let me log the service URL to the xunit output and see what was wrong.

Comment: It seems that you've found the cause of the issue yourself, and the `XUntil ITestOutputHelper` is what helped you to find the logs. Please consider adding your workaround as answer instead of comment here, so that members with similar issue can easily find your solution. You can then [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to indicate this thread is resolved, thx~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that a release pipeline URL variable was incorrect which caused the http client in a test to fail.  Ended up having to add some test code to use ITestOutputHelper to log the URL so we can easily see the service url in the event of test failure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)